# Putty alternative for Chrome OS

Tags: ssh, chrome-os

I'm looking for an alternative to [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) — a terminal and an SSH client — that works on Chrome OS.

I recently took a C++ course in which we used Putty and terminal to write programs. Are there any terminal emulators (if that is the right term to use) that work on a Chromebook for the purpose of practicing C++?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/708811/can-i-use-a-chromebook-as-a-ssh-workstation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Secure Shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog), a SSH client provided by Google on the Chrome Web Store.

> Secure Shell is an xterm-compatible terminal emulator and stand-alone ssh client for Chrome.  It uses Native-Client to connect directly to ssh servers without the need for external proxies.

This means you can SSH to an external server (just like using Putty), and from there use `nano`, `vim` or whatever you like to write C++ programs, then compile and execute from the terminal.

Comment: How do I sign into ssh? I'm being asked for user name, port, host, where do I find this information? Do you know of any tutorials